# Can jax.vmap() do a hstack()?

Tags: python, arrays, jax, google-jax

As the title says, I currently manually `hstack()` the first axis of a 3D array returned by `jax.vmap()`. In my code, the copy operation in `hstack()` is a currently a speed bottleneck. Can I avoid this by instructing `jax.vmap()` to do this directly?

Here is a simplified example:

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

def f(a, b, c):
  return jnp.array([[a.sum(), b.sum()], [c.sum(), 0.]]) # Returns a 2x2 array

def arr(m, n):
  return jnp.arange(m*n).reshape((m, n))

m = 3

a = arr(m, 2)
b = arr(m, 5)
c = arr(m, 7)

fv = jax.vmap(f)

vmap_output = fv(a, b, c)
desired_output = jnp.hstack(fv(a, b, c))

print(vmap_output)
print(desired_output)
```

This yields:

```py
# vmap() output
[[[  1.  10.]
  [ 21.   0.]]

 [[  5.  35.]
  [ 70.   0.]]

 [[  9.  60.]
  [119.   0.]]]
# Desired output
[[  1.  10.   5.  35.   9.  60.]
 [ 21.   0.  70.   0. 119.   0.]]
```

If this is not possible, I would resort to pre-allocating an array and simply writing to the columns manually, but I hope to avoid this. Thanks for any clue!

---

**Update from @jakevdp's answer**

Alright, it isn't possible. So I resort to writing to the columns, but this fails as well:

```py
def g(output, idx, a, b, c):
  block = jnp.array([[a.sum(), b.sum()], [c.sum(), 0.]]) # Returns a 2x2 array
  jax.lax.dynamic_update_slice_in_dim(output, block, idx*2, axis=1)

# Defined above: jax, jnp, m, a, b, c

g_output = jnp.zeros((2, 2*m))
idxs = jnp.arange(m)

gv = jax.vmap(g, in_axes=(None, 0, 0, 0, 0))

gv(g_output, idxs, a, b, c)

print(g_output)
```

This yields:

```py
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

So writing to `g_output` in the function `g` is not retained. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `vmap` does not have any built-in capability to stack outputs differently than the batching semantics would imply. But if you're interested in fusing the `hstack` operation with the `vmap` operation to the extent possible, you could do so by wrapping it in `jit`. For example:

```py
@jax.jit
def do_the_thing(a, b, c):
  return jnp.hstack(fv(a, b, c))

print(do_the_thing(a, b, c))
```

---

*Edit:* responding to your edited question: the reason the result is all zeros is because your function doesn't do anything: it returns `None`, so there's no way for it to affect the input array called `g_output`. JAX requires [pure functions](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#pure-functions) so side-effecting code like what you wrote above is not compatible. If you wanted to replace the `hstack` with an indexed update, you could do something like this:

```py
i = jnp.arange(2).reshape(1, 2, 1)
j = jnp.arange(6).reshape(3, 1, 2)
g_output = jnp.zeros((2, 2*m)).at[i, j].set(fv(a, b, c))
```

but a nontrivial `scatter` operation like this will not typically be faster than a simple `reshape`, especially if you're running on an accelerator like GPU.

If your arrays are large enough that reshapes are costly, you might find that a more direct implementation is better; for example:

```py
@jax.jit
def g(a, b, c):
  output = jnp.zeros((2, 6))
  output = output.at[0, 0::2].set(a.sum(1))
  output = output.at[0, 1::2].set(b.sum(1))
  output = output.at[1, 0::2].set(c.sum(1))
  return output

g_output = g(a, b, c)
```

Comment: Hi Jake, thanks for the fast reply! I already jit the hstack + vmap operation, so the speed bottleneck applies to the jitted thing. I updated the answer to include my attempt at writing to the columns directly. Could you take a look please? Cheers.

Comment: Have you done any benchmarking? `hstack` here lowers to a simple reshape – I really doubt that in-place updates are going to give you a performance boost over a simple reshape.

Comment: Yes, I used the jax profiler and in my log likelihood calculation the hstack operation takes up most of the time. Dimensions are O(1000) for number of rows and cols.

Comment: I guess the lowering to reshape depends on row major/column major ordering? I am on the CPU btw.

Comment: I responded to your edited code – you might try that approach (though I suspect it will be slower than the reshape).

Comment: Alright, thank you for the comprehensive answer.